# How to read properties file from one project into another project?

Tags: java, maven

I have two java projects A and B, If I have a credentials.properties file in A and I want to access the **same properties file** in project B, Is there a way I can achieve this?

The two projects are maven build.

Comment: why don't you copy the file into the new project? how large can a credential file be in size?

Comment: @Juvanis:  Copying resources between files can lead to out of date properties in projects, leading to hard-to-track bugs and aberrant behavior in the application.

Comment: @juvanis We should not make obviate duplicacy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<resource>
                <directory>${other projects dir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
```

Give the path as a full path

Comment: That's going to result in the properties file from project A being packaged up in project B.  If that's good enough, then this approach works; if not, you can create a project dependency from B to A and then load the properties file as a resource using [getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) or similar approaches.

Comment: @Tim Actually I have an X project which depends on A and B so the pom of X contains the reference of A and B.

Comment: @Prerit Tim is also right. That situation that u have mentioned is not a problem for that solution also.

Comment: Can I achieve this at project level?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the property file in the class path of B and set Project B as a dependency to project A.

Comment: Its a solution but Can't do this in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Commiting cleartext passwords into your source control is normally a bad idea...

How about using a shared Maven profile in your settings file? ($HOME/.m2/settings.xml):

```
<settings>
    ..
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>credentials</dev>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <properties>
                <password1>XXXXX</password1>
                <password2>YYYYY</password2>
                ..
                ..
            </properties>
        </profile>
        ..
    </profiles>
    ..
</settings>
```

This approach is more Maven friendly and [encryption is supported](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

If you use Jenkins to build your code, you can use a plugin to manage the settings file centrally:

- [How to manage maven settings.xml on a shared jenkins server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685515/how-to-manage-maven-settings-xml-on-a-shared-jenkins-server/16703882#16703882)

Your project  can still have a default value, the key point is that the real passwords are set externally to files under source control.