# jenkins on windows | change .m2 path

Tags: windows, path, jenkins

I just want to change the .m2 path of a jenkins project in maven. Everytime when I build the project the .m2 folder is in c:\ and empty! There's no settings.xml or something...

The .m2 path of eclipse is in user.home (that's okay).

But how can I change the path of the .m2 folder in jenkins?

Thank you guys ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage maven settings.xml on a shared jenkins server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685515/how-to-manage-maven-settings-xml-on-a-shared-jenkins-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `project configuration` page of Jenkin, under the tab `Build`, select `Invoke Maven` and click on `Advanced`. There is a check box `Use private Maven repository`. If this is selected, Jenkins will tell Maven to use $WORKSPACE/.repository as the local Maven repository.
Click on the help topic  in Jenkin itself. It will give a clear idea.

If you need to invoke maven out side this plugin, you can pass

`-Dmaven.repo.local=/some/path/.maven/repo`