# How to stop maven from installing artifacts to local repository?

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

I have added following repository to my maven configuration.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>android</id>
        <url>file://${env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

After that I have noticed that during build on Jenkins artifacts are installed in that repository instead in `~/.m2/repository`.
I can't reproduce the same behavior on my local machine.

How can I mark that repository as read only so that artifacts are installed in `~/.m2/repository`?

Comment: Don't define this kind of repositories in your pom. Better start using a repository manager and store the artifacts there instead.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685515/how-to-manage-maven-settings-xml-on-a-shared-jenkins-server/16703882#16703882

Comment: @khmarbaise I would setup repository manager if I could, in this case I can't

Answer (score 0):

When you want to only install in the local repository, you should be using

> mvn clean install

not

> mvn clean deploy

Both of these build up until the install lifecycle phase, but the second one then tries to execute the deploy lifecycle phase.  The install lifecycle phase is where artifacts are installed to the local repository, so deploy is not needed in this case.  You also, as khmarbaise said, shouldn't be using a file path for the repository but instead a web path to a repository manager such as Nexus or Artifactory if you do want to deploy (i.e. don't use the local filesystem for this).

Comment: I know about maven's lifecycle. Unfortunately your answer doesn't help me.