# Unable to configure Maven in Jenkins 2.7.2

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am unable to configure Maven in Jenkins version 2.7.2
When trying to configure from Configure Systems in Manage Jenkins, unable to understand where to add Maven repository path.
[Configure Systems screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwQ1P.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage maven settings.xml on a shared jenkins server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685515/how-to-manage-maven-settings-xml-on-a-shared-jenkins-server)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Jenkins / Manage Jenkins / Global Tool Configuration and add a Maven installation, either pointing to an existing directory or installing a new one.